# need SYNTAX to read the SelectedValues (selectList value) in picklist (selectoptions) which is in <APEX:REPEAT>

Tags: visualforce, picklist, repeat

I need SYNTAX to read the SelectedValues (selectList value) 
in picklist (selectoptions) which is in apex:repeat tag.

My Vf code:

```
   <table border="1" width="100%">
      <apex:REPEAT value="{!ques}" var="singleQuestion">
       <tr>
           <td> {!singleQuestion} </td>
           <td>
               <apex:selectList value="{!Selectedvalues}" size="1">
                   <apex:selectoptions value="{!objectivetype}" />
               </apex:selectList>
           </td>
       </tr>
     </apex:repeat>
</table>
In Controller:
--------------
public List<String> Selectedvalues{get; set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably simplest to add a small nested class that holds the pair of values to your controller:

```
public class Question {
    public String label;
    public String answer;
}

public List<Question> questions {get ; set;}
```

so that your Visualforce can be simple:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
   <apex:REPEAT value="{!questions}" var="question">
   <tr>
       <td> {!question.label} </td>
       <td>
           <apex:selectList value="{!quesion.answer}" size="1">
               <apex:selectoptions value="{!objectivetype}" />
           </apex:selectList>
       </td>
   </tr>
   </apex:repeat>
</table>
```

Otherwise you will need to add a loop counter to your Visualforce using apex:variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go through the following links for more clarification

[Apex:Repeat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm)

[SelectList](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectList.htm)

[SelectOption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectOption.htm)